# CSS properties for general 'Formatters' in a Google Visualization Table

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

Google visualization API's include 'Formatters' which allow you to use things like colored text and arrows representing qualities of data. More information on formatters can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters).

Now, when I edit the CSS values of the table, or use configurtion options (found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Configuration_Options)), tables that use fomatters seem to have trouble displaying certain CSS properties i.e, width of cells and text size. An example I've noticed where this is the case when the entire tables text is a smaller than default font, and a row is selected. That row which was selected will revert back to a 10pt Arial font when deselected.

Although this specific instance is annoying, I am curious about **ALL** formatter css properties and their class names. There is no information, to my knowledge, on the Google developer site.

These are my class names:

```
        'headerRow': 'header-cells',
            'tableRow': '.even-background all-cells',
            'oddTableRow': 'odd-background all-cells',
            'selectedTableRow': 'all-cells',
            'hoverevenTableRow': '',
            'hoveroddrTableRow': '',
            'headerCell': 'header-cells white bold darkgreen-background',
            'tableCell': 'all-cells'
    };
```

These are the formatters being used.

```
 var changecolor = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
            changecolor.addRange(null, 0, 'red', 'none');
            changecolor.addRange(0.000001, null, 'green', 'none');
            changecolor.format(dt, 1); // Apply formatter to second column

            var parens = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
                prefix: "$",
                negativeParens: true
            });
            parens.format(dt, 1); // Apply formatter to second column

                var arrow = new google.visualization.ArrowFormat();
                arrow.format(dt, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
  var FormatAll = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
                prefix: "$",
                pattern: '#.00##'
            });
```

Style properties:

```
 <style>
    .all-cells {
        border: 0px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 9px;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    .header-cells {
        border: 0px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 9px;
        padding-right: 0;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .darkgreen-background {
        background-color: #0B3B0B;
    }
    .odd-background {
        background-color: #E6F8E0;
    }
    .even-background {
        background-color: #FFF5E3;
    }
    .bold {
        font-weight: bold
    }
    .White {
        fontcolor: white;
    }
    </style>
```

[JS fiddle script in action](http://jsfiddle.net/musclez/1q8yk4f5/)

If you notice, when a cell is selected, the font size changes. This only happens when the `google.visualization.ArrowFormat` is applied.

I'd like to get rid of the boarder of the table, but that is not affected by classname or class properties (refer to the fiddle),

There is also a conflict with the `parens.format` and `google.visualization.NumberFormat`. Decimals places do not display with parentheses.

**Not directly shown in code or fiddle:** cell width properties become offset with cells that have formatters applied to them.

Comment: The hover and select effects should not have permanent effects on the style of the rows.  If you can provide a code sample that demonstrates this effect, we can look into it and see what is going on.  If you're interested in the base CSS for the tables, you can see the current version [here](https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/dee027d0b48a2e0a0a0375d00d7dd635/ui+en,table+en.css).

Comment: asgallant, i included the code and a fiddle. thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things going on here.  First, the ArrowFormat overrides all other classes placed on a cell, so those cells do not have the `all-cells` class.  This is fine, as long as the `<tr>` has the `all-cells` class.  The `<tr>`'s lose the `all-cells` class when you deselect them, because `all-cells` is part of both the even/odd row and selected row classes (and deselecting a row removes whatever classes you put on it.

If the reason you put `all-cells` as the selected row class is because you don't want the style from the default class, I suggest changing the class to something that has no styles associated with it, like this:

```
'selectedTableRow': 'noStyle'
```

Also, on a side note, you have a typo in the even row classes: there should not be a `.` before `even-background`:

```
'tableRow': 'even-background all-cells'
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/1q8yk4f5/3/

Comment: Sorry for the type as i was doing some edits as i was typing in the questions.
I ran through your example. It not does seem to include any of my formatters. If you organize the chart by any of the columns, the selected row will change font. I'm not sure exactly what you think you did, but The same issues are still there.

I understand that formatters override other css properties. This is why I am looking for other CSS classnames, or css class properties that correlate to formatters specifically.

Comment: You're right - selected rows are losing their custom classes on sorting; you can file a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) on this.  The table-specific formatters (ArrowFormat, BarFormat, ColorFormat) apply classes or inline-styles to cells; the specifics are not documented, your best bet is to use a DOM inspector to examine the table and look at what the formatters are doing.

Comment: I've checked through the bug reports on a few relating issues and it doesn't seem like they have spoken about on Google's part since 2008. I was hoping to find some more information on Stacks. If you do not mind, please show some appreciation for the research effort so this topic can be pushed along to others who may have more knowledge. Once again, thank you, [**asgallant**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/613559/asgallant). You have helped me more than once with Google-Visualization and JavaScript issues.